# Groovy's .collect() equivalent on C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, groovy, collections

I would like to know if there is a method in C# that transforms each element of a collection to something I like?

This is my current code in summing up a row of data:

```
// C#
int sum = 0;
foreach (DataGridView row in gridView.Rows)
{
   sum += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Amount"]);
}
```

I'm looking for a solution to use C#'s `.Sum()` method.

In groovy, I can do this to sum the collection:

```
// Groovy
int sum = rows.collect { it.cells.amount as Integer }.sum()
```

Is this possible in C#, like LINQ or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try LINQ.

You'll need to add a reference to System.LINQ (and a `using System.Linq;`), if you don't already have one.

You could then sum the values you need up using the following statement:

```
int sum = gridView.Rows.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Amount"]));
```

Comment: This is just perfect!

Comment: :) Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Sum` extension method:

```
var sum = gridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Amount"]));
```

You should use `OfType` first because `DataGridViewRowCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but only `IEnumerable`